# error: invalid operands of types 'int' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'

Tags: c++

i want to get the 6th bit of 48th character of z_Data

```
{
    char c = pPkt->z_Data[47];                // this z_Data is a char buffer
    std::cout<<(c>>3)&1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<(c>>4)&1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<(c>>5)&1<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `<<` (and `>>`) are higher in precedence than `&`.

Comment: As to why `&` has low precedence: originally in C's development `&&` didn't exist; `&` was also used for logical AND. `>>` was bit-shifting, so for the intent `a >> b AND c` , it was natural that `&` had the lower precedence.  When they added `&&` they didn't want to change existing code that worked with `&`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<<` has a higher precedence than that of `&`, so you need:

```
std::cout << ((c >> 3) & 1) << std::endl;
std::cout << ((c >> 4) & 1) << std::endl;
std::cout << ((c >> 5) & 1) << std::endl;
```